# Apache Camel. Проблемы передачи файлов. Запуск маршута из другого маршрута

Tags: java, apache, camel

В папку на сервере присылаются архивы с файлами внутри. Мне необходимо разархивировать содержимое и выполнить агрегацию файлов с одинаковым названием. Маршруты есть, все в принципе работает, но есть некоторые проблемы:

1. Когда я, например, с локального компьютера скидываю архив размером более 2-3 мб, то загрузка происходит не мгновенно, то есть все зависит от скорости передачи файла. Архив еще полностью не успел прогрузиться, а мой первый маршрут уже начинает его разархивировать в другую папку, маршрут с агрегацией начинает свою работу с поступающими файлами и когда он ищет файлы с одинаковыми именами, то не всегда находит его пару, т.к. не все еще прогрузилось с первого маршрута. Как решить такую проблему? Как сделать, чтобы файлы полностью все извлекались из архива и только потом начинать агрегацию?
2. Как поступить лучше, если ожидается что будет приходить не один архив, а их может быть отправлено несколько, причем и одновременно и последовательно?

В Apache Camel я новичок, сильно не пинайте. Ниже прилагаю свои маршруты:

```
<route id="packageLoad">
    <from uri="file:///home/zipfiles/"/>
    <log message="start packageLoad"/>
    <setHeader headerName="zipFileName">
        <simple>${file:onlyname.noext}</simple>
    </setHeader>
    <unmarshal ref="zipFileDataFormat"/>
    <split streaming="true">
        <setBody>
            <simple>${body}</simple>
        </setBody>
        <to uri="file:///home/unzipfiles/"/>
    </split>
</route>

<route id="aggregate">
    <from uri="file:///home/unzipfiles/"/>
    <log message="start aggregation"/>
    <aggregate strategyRef="myStrategy" completionTimeout="5000">
        <correlationExpression>
            <simple>${file:onlyname.noext}</simple>
        </correlationExpression>
        <completionSize>
            <simple>2</simple>
        </completionSize>
        <to uri="jms:signValidate"/>
    </aggregate>
</route>
```

Comment: Возможно, лучше будет извлекать файлы из архива в генерируемую папку и как-то передавать ее название в маршрут с агрегацией.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поставьте на потребителях параметр readLock=changed вот так

```
<from uri="file:///home/zipfiles/?readLock=changed"/>
<from uri="file:///home/unzipfiles/?readLock=changed"/>
```

Тогда ваш маршрут будет потреблять только скачанные файлы.

Что касается вопроса заливки нескольких архивов, то если вам нужно обрабатывать один архив за раз значит проблем не будет. Маршрут будет потреблять и обрабатывать по очереди каждый скачанный архив по одному.

Comment: Спасибо! Есть ли смысл в readLockCheckInterval и readLockTimeout?

Comment: Для локальных файлов особого смысла менять дефолты не вижу. В случае потребителей файлов через ftp или smb, бывает иногда нужно поиграться значениями. Ну или если у вас маршрут запускается редко по расписанию, и вам точно нужно дождаться закачки файла и обработать его, тогда значения нужно увеличить. Но это не ваш случай, у вас file-компонент проверяет папку раз в пол-секунды(параметр  delay)